# How to stop Windows 7 grouping/consolidating several printers under one printer item in Devices and Printers?

Tags: windows-7, drivers, printing

How can Windows be configured NOT to group several printers under one printer - shown as one item in Printers and Faxes in Control Panel\Hardware and Sound\Devices and Printers?

**Background**

Reason for question:

I am using a label editing program that stores the printer model in the label file. I need to support several printers to print the label so I create a file for each printer. However, I only have one printer model at my desk and I just need to test print the labels for all models on this printer even though I don't have all of the models on my desk. But I can't get the label to print, so I suspect it is something to do with how the printers are being grouped.

My colleagues' machines have the same setup and they can print successfully all labels, but on their machines, Windows 7 does not group the printers under one item, each different printer model is shown as a separate item.

**Research**

I have tried looking here but no conclusive solution:
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/w7itproui/thread/cf1148ac-17f0-4783-9aa9-34216377b597

Comment: You can add multiple 'Printers' but all with the same destination Port/IP address etc. I do it here, default printer is a network printer, grey scale, high compression, medium quality and double sided (to lower toner use, increase speed and reduce paper use). I have another printer installed (same printer, IP & driver) with the opposite settings for photo printing.

Comment: That's exactly what I did, but then Windows decided to group them under one item following a reboot.

Comment: I assume you have looked at the "view" settings for printers and devices?

Comment: Does each printer have its own individual entry in the classic "Printers" folder?  You can open that folder by entering `start shell:::{26EE0668-A00A-44D7-9371-BEB064C98683}\0\::{2227A280-3AEA-1069-A2DE-08002B30309D}` in a command prompt.

Comment: @JoshTownzen that doesn't work here (Win7 Pro 32bit)

Comment: It seems i'm lucky my Printers havn't grouped... Yet!

Answer (score 2):

You will have to create a new port with the printer settings, but make sure the port name is different. If the port names are the same it will group them, changing the port name will solve your issue.

Comment: More information [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2015694) and the link you mentioned in the question [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sv-SE/w7itproui/thread/cf1148ac-17f0-4783-9aa9-34216377b597) gives information about changing the port name to work around the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to create a new port with the printer settings, but make sure the port name is different. If the port names are the same it will group them, changing the port name will solve your issue.

Add the port names *in advance of adding the printer* - don't use the port name suggested by Windows. Add a second port by going into the print server properties, and instead of the suggested suffix of _1, use something like _B. For instance, if the hostname of the printer was CORP1028, when adding a second port, use a port name of CORP1028_B. Then close the print server properties box. Then click on Add New Printer button, and when prompted for the port, choose the newly created port.